# Amazon S3 accesskey storage?

Tags: c#, security, amazon-s3

I'm building a web application using amazon S3 as storage, and I was wondering if it's safe having the access key and the secret access key in plain text static string in the source code? I might be paranoid, but I'm not quite sure if I'm basically just handing out the access keys by doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put it in an app config or DB, that way you can change it if it gets compromised.